# How to copy just certain words from a file into a new file

Tags: grep, cp

I have a homework assignment where I have a file that is a large list of words. 
I have to copy into a new file all the words starting with `c` and name it `cwords`.

I can see a list of the words by doing `cat words | grep ^c` and I can copy the entire list to a file by doing `cp words cwords` but what do I type to get just the words starting with `c` copied over?

Comment: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/22142)

Comment: @jpaugh, it's exactly the correct regex, see e.g. [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking! I was thinking of the control character.

Comment: +1 for the honesty that it's homework. My inner middle-schooler would give an additional +1 for the new file's required name.

Answer (score 0):

here is the `>` or `1>` redirection of stdout to a file your are looking for 
`-i` option set on grep means ignore case 
you don't need `cat file | grep ...` 
just use `grep`

there are few different type of redirection to learn to use.

```
grep yourpattern inputfile > outputfile
```

```
-bash-4.4$ cat > cword\? # to have a random file list as input
fdsf
fdsfsd
cdsfdsf
csrezr
rezr
ret
```

```
-bash-4.4$ grep -i "^c" cword\? > cwords 
-bash-4.4$ cat cwords
cdsfdsf
csrezr
-bash-4.4$ rm cword*
-bash-4.4$
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy the Words beginning with c to new file

command

```
sed -n '/^c/p' inputfile >outputfile
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -E '\bc' inputfile > outputfile
```

I should elaborate 
-E, --extended-regexp
\b is word boundries
c is the character you want to match
so you're searching through inputfile for all words that start with c
you then use > to put the output in outputfile.  In your case, you wold name it cwords.

Comment: make sure you go back and read my explanation, just giving you the answer is not going to help you.